# ¿Como hago una matriz de 3 x 3 en pseint en la que el usuario ingrese los numeros?

Tags: pseint

Necesito construir un algoritmo que recorra una matriz de 3 x 3 debo llenar esta matriz antes, imprima todos los números que estén bajo un valor ingresado por el usuario.

```
Algoritmo  Arreglo
  Dimension A[3,3];
  Definir A Como Entero;
  Definir i Como Entero;
  Definir j como entero;

  Para i<-0 Hasta 2 Con Paso 1 Hacer
    Escribir "De un numero";
    Leer A[i,j];
  FinPara

  Para i<-0 Hasta 2 Con Paso 1 Hacer
    Escribir Sin Saltar A[i,j];       
  FinPara

FinAlgoritmo
```

Comment: no se como editar para poner bien la parte de arriba la que dice Algoritmo Arreglo Dimension A[3,3]; Definir A Como Entero; Definir i Como Entero; Definir j como entero; se me sale de el codigo.

Answer (score 1):

Bajo el supuesto que tienes configurado `PseInt` para usar indices de arreglos desde cero (0) deberías hacer algo así:

```
Algoritmo  Arreglo
    Dimension A[3,3];
    Definir A Como Entero;
    Definir i Como Entero;
    Definir j como entero;
    
    Para i<-0 Hasta 2 Con Paso 1 Hacer
        Para j<-0 Hasta 2 Con Paso 1 Hacer
            Escribir "De un numero";
            Leer A[i,j];
        Fin Para
    FinPara
    
    Para i<-0 Hasta 2 Con Paso 1 Hacer            
        Escribir ""; //Esto es solo para dar un poco de formato
        Para j<-0 Hasta 2 Con Paso 1 Hacer
            Escribir Sin Saltar A[i,j] " ";
        Fin Para        
    FinPara     
FinAlgoritmo
```

Muestra en funcionamiento:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Anexe una muestra de la aplicación corriendo.